# How can I make go get hooks for my go project?

Tags: go

Example: In a project with protobuffers, how can I require that when the package is go get'd, the protobuffers are compiled before attempting to build?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible use Go build with extra build steps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402956/is-it-possible-use-go-build-with-extra-build-steps)

Comment: if you are using protobuf I would suggest to commit generated code along with proto files. This way the library won't require protoc compiler being available on the user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add hook to `go get` build but you could use [`go generate`](http://blog.golang.org/generate) to get protobuffers compiled when compiling your go code.